# Using SelectSingleNode with XML file, node repeats twice

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

Here's a file I'm trying to parse. I can get data from `<countryName>` and `<countryAbbrev>`, but getting an error when trying to read `<gml:name>` node. Note that this node appears twice in XML file, on the top level and under `<Hostip>` node.
Here's a syntax I'm using:

- This one works - `doc.SelectSingleNode("//countryName")`
- This one doesn't - `doc.SelectSingleNode("//gml:name")`

Any ideas?

```
<HostipLookupResultSet xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.1" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hostip.info/api/hostip-1.0.1.xsd">
    <gml:description>This is the Hostip Lookup Service</gml:description>
    <gml:name>hostip</gml:name>
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Null>inapplicable</gml:Null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <Hostip>
            <ip>24.205.216.31</ip>
            <gml:name>Carson City, NV</gml:name>
            <countryName>UNITED STATES</countryName>
            <countryAbbrev>US</countryAbbrev>
            <ipLocation>
                <gml:pointProperty>
                    <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                        <gml:coordinates>-119.763,39.233</gml:coordinates>
                    </gml:Point>
                </gml:pointProperty>
            </ipLocation>
        </Hostip>
    </gml:featureMember>
</HostipLookupResultSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) for the `xmlns` alias `gml`. Try like so:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmanager.AddNamespace("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");

Debug.WriteLine(doc.SelectSingleNode("//countryName").InnerText);
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//gml:name", nsmanager))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Result:

```
UNITED STATES 
hostip 
Carson City, NV
```

**Edit**

Just a thought, if you are trying to access just one of the `gml:name` nodes, the following xpaths will navigate a subtree for the first and second respectively:

```
//HostipLookupResultSet/gml:name/text()
//HostipLookupResultSet/gml:featureMember/gml:name/Hostip/text()
```